# How to use S3 with Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Problem: I have a zip file which cant be directly uploaded to lambda as it is timing out

What i want is to upload the zip file to S3 and lambda function to execute the zip file from S3 somehow ?

can someone please explain how i can approach this problem ? (I am using NODE 12.x for my lambda)

**EDIT**

I want to use the aws cli for the lambda to get a file from s3 please suggest a command ?

**Clarification**

The zip file contains index.js and node_modules its a typical zip file which is uploaded to lambda

Comment: What do you mean by "execute the zip file"? Do you mean unzip the zip file (onto the local file system of the Lambda function)? And how large is the zip file typically?

Comment: What do you mean by "uploaded to lambda"? Does the Zip file contain code for Lambda to execute, or is it being _used_ by your Lambda function? Please tell us more about what you are actually wanting to accomplish.

Comment: What i meant by execute the zip file was how lambda typically executes when we upload a zip file containing index.js and other modules

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use the AWS SDK for NodeJS instead of using the AWS CLI. Either way, you should configure the S3 bucket to trigger the Lambda function on new object creation. Then the Lambda function can pull the S3 object's key out of the event data that is passed into it, download the object from S3 into the Lambda execution environment's `/tmp` folder, and do whatever you want from there.